# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Currently we moved our Web Applications to a new server so now we have a Database and Web + App Server. Before moving everything was working fine.

But now as we have installed SQL Server on the DB Server we are getting errors related to:

**`Microsoft.SqlServer`** DLL files.

So basically the code runs a script on the DB server to create a New Database.

First I was getting the Error, related to: `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll`

So I installed, the nuget Package: `Shared Management Objects`

[image]

Which seemed to have fix the Problem.

BUT now I am getting an error related to `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser`

I followed the links online and they suggest to install:

**Shared Management Objects** from here; https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065

> Note; we are using SQL server 2012 standard.

So I installed `Shared Management Objects` and also restarted the server, but I am still getting the same error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I navigate to: C:\Windows\assembly I can see that `Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser`:

[image]

The Exception occurs on this line of code:

```
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

Comment: Have you installed the SQLServer Native Client on your server?

Comment: You need to turn on Fusion logging.  That tells you where the runtime is looking for your batchparser dll.

Comment: @BerndLinde On the DB Server or App Server? It is installed on the DB Server

Comment: If the error is on your App Server then there, if the error is on your DB Server, there is something else wrong

Comment: The error is on App Server  @BerndLinde

Comment: Then install the Native Client on your App Server and let your application run. [SQLNICL from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-PK/download/details.aspx?id=43339). Select either the 32 or 64 bit of "sqlncli.msi". That should solve the references missing issue since the DLLs that it is looking for are not present on the server

Comment: @BerndLinde Ok I'll give it a try

Comment: In your screenshot of `C:\Windows\assembly` we can't see the version number of `BacthParserClient`. Can you confirm that it is `v11`?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin yes it is 11

Comment: Hi @DawoodAwan, I am also in a trouble with same isue. Could you fix it? If yes, can you share the solution with me. Thanks in advence.